# Proving if $A$ is an $n\times n$ positive semi-definite matrix, A is Hermitian with non-negative eigenvalues.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a test on Monday and the professor hinted that this question might be relevant to the exam, unfortunately, I'm at a loss.

As the title states, I would like to prove that if $A$ is an $n\times n$ positive semi-definite matrix then $A$ is Hermitian with non-negative eigenvalues.

I would love to be able to work through this and I hope someone can lend a hand.

Thank you very much.

Comment: How do you define positive semidefinite? Compute $\langle v , Av \rangle$ for a unit eigenvector.

Comment: @copper.hat Positive semidefinite is defined as $x^*Ax\ge0, \forall x\in\mathbb{C}_n$. So if $v$ is a unit eigenvector, then we can write $\left<v,\lambda v\right> = \lambda\left<v,v\right> = \lambda\ge0$. This tells us that every eigenvalue is $\ge0$.

Comment: Does your definition of positive semidefinite also imply Hermitian?

Comment: @copper.hat I'm not sure how, that's what I want to prove. The previous comment showed the 'non-negative eigenvalues' of the proof but not that it's actually Hermitian, at least not that I can see.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, prove that if $E$ is a Hermitian matrix then $w^*Ew\in\mathbb{R}$, for every vector $w$.

Second, prove that every complex matrix $A$ can be writen as $A=B+iC$, where $B$ and $C$ are Hermitians.

Let $c$ be an eigenvalue of $C$ and $v$ an associated normalized eigenvector. Notice that $c\in\mathbb{R}$.

Thus, $v^*Av=v^*Bv+iv^*Cv=v^*Bv+ic$. Since a $v^*Av$ must be a positive real number, we must conclude  that $c=0$(why?).

This implies $C=0$ (why?). Therefore A is Hermitian.

Comment: Thank you, but I have a question. Why must $v^*Av$ be a positive real number? I know this must be true if $A$ is Hermitian but how do we know it's true if $A$ is any complex matrix?

Comment: @Eric, $v^*Av\in\mathbb{R}$ for every $v$ iff $A$ is Hermtian. If your definition of positive semidefinite matrix is $v^*Av\geq 0$ for every $v$ then $A$ is Hermitian and has non-negative eigenvalues.

Answer (score -1):

Let $(\alpha, v)$ be an eigenpair of $A$. Then

$$v^{*}Av = v^{*}(Av) = \alpha v^{*}v = \alpha||v||^{2}.$$
As $A$ is positive semi definite $\Rightarrow \alpha||v||^{2} \ge 0$. But $||v||^{2} > 0 \Rightarrow \alpha \ge 0$.

Comment: @MaoWao $v$ is a vector over $\mathbb{C}$. If you are working over $\mathbb{R}$, replace $v^{*}$ by $v^{T}$.

Comment: You seem to assume that $v*A v$ uniquely determines $A$. This needs a proof (and is wrong over $\mathbb{R}$, as the example of a 90° rotation shows).

Comment: @MaoWao No assumption is made here. I used the definition of matrix A being positive semi-definite.

Comment: See, if you take $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$, then $v^T A v=v^T 0v$ for all $v\in \mathbb R^2$, yet $A\neq 0$. So you need to justify why $v^\ast A v=v^\ast A^\ast v$ implies $A=A^\ast$.